# UICollectionView / TableView Memory Allocation Issue with Base64 images

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, memory-management, uiimage, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView / UITableView showing images, as I scroll through the images the memory allocation gradually grows and eventually crashes my device.

To create my objects for the UICollectionView / UITableView I have a builder class where I generate my objects from JSON (Included in this JSON is a Base64 string of an image). After creating these objects I put them into an NSArray and then pass them to the UICollectionView / UITableView.

The memory allocation issue happens when (in the builder class) I create my UIImage from Base64:

```
NSData *dataFromString = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64 options:0];
UIImage *image         = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:dataFromString];
```

But if I create my UIImage from a png/jpg (again in the builder class) I have no issues (i.e. the memory allocation does not grow):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

I used instruments and there appear to be no memory leaks, and when I dismiss the UICollectionView / UITableView the memory footprint goes down, but Im at a loss as to why the difference seems to be the use of Base64.

Thanks in advance

Carl.

Comment: instead of `imageNamed` i would try `initWithContentsOfFile`. the `imageNamed` function adds cacheing and some extra memory management and is not really good for comparing memory usage.

Comment: thanks for the tip... changing the code to 'initWithContentsOfFile' does indeed cause the same memory growth in my app. This gives me something else to investigate thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating a tempFileManger class, I then write the UIImages to a temporary directory as PNG:

```
 NSString *path = [tempDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageObject.title];
 NSData *data   = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageObject.image);
```

Then in my cellForItemAtIndexPath method I retrieve using the following:

```
NSString *path = [tempDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageObject.title];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Once I have finished using the images I delete all the images in the temp folder using my tempFileManagerClass.

```
   NSArray *contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:tempDir error:nil];

    for (NSString *filename in contents)  {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[tempDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];
    }
```